# Pandas: Locating and updating values based on row content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dictionary of the following format:

```
MyDict = {"string1" : 10, "string2" : 20, "string3" : 30, ...}
```

I also have a large DataFrame with the following format:

```
  col1              col2  
0       string1                 1 
1       string2                 2  
2       string3                 1
3       string1                 3   
4       string3                 4
5       string1                 5
```

I want to find values where col1 != string1 and change the values based on the row content and the dictionary I initially mentioned:

```
df.loc[df["col1"] != "string1" , "col2"] = df["col2"] * MyDict[df["col1"]]
```

(I immediately realised this would not be possible with the above usage of loc, and sure enough: **Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed**)

A representation of the desired output:

```
  col1              col2  
0       string1                 1 
1       string2                 40  
2       string3                 30
3       string1                 3   
4       string3                 120
5       string1                 5
```

What would be the correct way to approach this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) on the boolean masked df and pass the dict which will perform the lookup and multiply the column against the result of the returned Series:

```
In [273]:
MyDict = {"string1" : 10, "string2" : 20, "string3" : 30}
df.loc[df["col1"] != "string1" , "col2"] *= df['col1'].map(MyDict)
df

Out[273]:
      col1  col2
0  string1     1
1  string2    40
2  string3    30
3  string1     3
4  string3   120
5  string1     5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think better is use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for condition:

```
MyDict = {"string1" : 10, "string2" : 20, "string3" : 30}

df.loc[~df["col1"].str.contains("string1") , "col2"] *= df["col1"].map(MyDict)
print df
      col1  col2
0  string1     1
1  string2    40
2  string3    30
3  string1     3
4  string3   120
5  string1     5
```